# Accessing shared_examples defined across contexts is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rspec on my rails app, and I updated my gems. Now when I run my tests, I have the following message :

```rb
Accessing shared_examples defined across contexts is deprecated.
Please declare shared_examples within a shared context, or at the top level.
This message was generated at: /home/flo/RoR/letroquet/spec/requests/user_show_page_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the **user_show_page_spec.rb**

```rb
describe "show user page" do

  subject { page }

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:current_page) { user_path(user) }

  describe "aside info" do

    describe "when not signed-in" do
      before { visit current_page }

      it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }

      it_should_behave_like "another user products count" # This is the 50th line
    end
  end
end
```

And here the **spec/support/users/info.rb**

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "products count" do
  subject { page }

  shared_examples_for "another user products count" do
    before { visit current_page }

    it { should have_selector('b', text: t('product.owned.count', count: user.transactions.current.ownership.count)) }
    it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.givable.count', count: user.products.owned.givable.count)) }
    it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.sharable.count', count: user.products.owned.sharable.count)) }
    it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.borrowed.count', count: user.products.borrowed.count)) }

    it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.given.count', count: user.products.given.count)) }
    it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.returned.count', count: user.products.returned.count)) }

  end
end
```

Can you tell me how I must change my tests files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subject is discussed in http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/rspec-2-14-is-released and examples given in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Per that documentation, you need to place the examples within the scope of their use by direct inclusion or the use of 'require'. In any event, note that the `shared_examples_for` invocation needs to be within the scope, it can't be buried within a `describe` as is currently the case with the code in `info.rb`.

So, assuming that your `spec_helper.rb` file is already automatically including the files in `spec/support`, you could change your `info.rb` file to be:

```
shared_examples_for "another user products count" do
  subject { page }
  before { visit current_page }

  it { should have_selector('b', text: t('product.owned.count', count: user.transactions.current.ownership.count)) }
  it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.givable.count', count: user.products.owned.givable.count)) }
  it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.sharable.count', count: user.products.owned.sharable.count)) }
  it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.borrowed.count', count: user.products.borrowed.count)) }

  it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.given.count', count: user.products.given.count)) }
  it { should have_selector('li', text: t('product.returned.count', count: user.products.returned.count)) }

end
```

and it should work. Note that the `subject` call was moved within the shared example block.